# GPS coordinates without internet using cordova geolocation plugin

Tags: android, cordova, gps, cordova-plugins

I'll make an Android app using the cordova geolocation plugin but I want to know if its possible to use it to retrieve lat/long coordinates only with gps on and without internet.

I saw some post where there are a cold NO as answer and others where developers get coordinates even with gps turned off.

1.- Can you tell me if its possible or not and why?

2.- Is there another way to get gps locations WITHOUT interaction with offline maps? (I want to get coordinates only pressing a button)

3.- If is not possible using cordova plugin is possible by another way?

4.- Can you give me additional advices or thoughts regarding this topic?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible if the user at the localization of activated of course.

I haven't put it into production yet and therefore not tested enough, but I have already developed a button that allows this.

You must use the plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

### According to the documentation, you should do something like that :

```
// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

I do have some doubts about offline operation on ios.